# expected css "title" Hartl's Tutorial Chapter 5 Exercises

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am working through [Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 5 exercises](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-layout_exercises) and I keep getting a failing test that I cannot figure out.

I'm working with the click_link problem and All the caps match and the I believe all the other files are correct. I'm really not sure what's wrong here. I've tried restarting Spork. And whenever I comment out the first click_link test, it pull up an error for the second one and so on... Feel free to take a look at the code at http://github.com/sambaek/sample_app.

Can someone help me out? Thanks a bunch!

### spec/support/utilities.rb

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

### spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  subject { page }

  shared_examples_for "all static pages" do
    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: heading) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title(page_title)) }
  end

  describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }

    let(:heading)    { 'Sample App' }
    let(:page_title) { '' }

    it_should_behave_like "all static pages"
    it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: '| Home' }
  end

  describe "Help page" do
    before { visit help_path }

    let(:heading)    { 'Help' }
    let(:page_title) { 'Help' }

    it_should_behave_like "all static pages"  
  end

  describe "About page" do
    before { visit about_path }

    let(:heading)    { 'About Us' }
    let(:page_title) { 'About Us' }

    it_should_behave_like "all static pages"
  end

  describe "Contact page" do
    before { visit contact_path }

    let(:heading)    { 'Contact' }
    let(:page_title) { 'Contact' }

    it_should_behave_like "all static pages"
  end

  it "should have the right links on the layout" do
    visit root_path
    click_link "About"
    page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('About Us')
    click_link "Help"
    page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('Help')
    click_link "Contact"
    page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('Contact')
    click_link "Home"
    click_link "Sign up now!"
    page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('Sign Up')
    click_link "sample app"
    page.should_not have_selector 'title', text: full_title(' | Home')
  end
end
```

### spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do

  describe "full_title" do
    it "should include the page title" do
      full_title("foo").should =~ /foo/
    end

    it "should include the base title" do
      full_title("foo").should =~ /^Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App/
    end

    it "should not include a bar for the home page" do
      full_title("").should_not =~ /\|/
    end
  end
end
```

### app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def full_title(page_title)
        base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
        if page_title.empty?
            base_title
        else
            "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
        end
    end
end
```

### Terminal Output

```
rspec spec/

..F............

Failures:

  1) Static pages should have the right links on the layout
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('About Us')
       expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 4.37 seconds
15 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:49 # Static pages should have the right links on the layout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because your links in `layouts/footer` and `layouts/header` don't go anywhere. They're *clickable* by the spec, but they just go to `#` rather than their proper page. If you correct these links then the spec will work.

In `app/views/layouts/_footer.html.erb`:

```
<li><%= link_to "About",   '/about' %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Contact", '/contact' %></li>
```

In `app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb`:

```
 <li><%= link_to "Home",    '/' %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "Help",    '/help' %></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not continue to use the named route path vars (e.g. about_path)?